# Unable to trigger Lambda from Kinesis Consumer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis

I have a lambda which consumes near-real time updates from a DynamoDB table through a Kinesis Data Stream. I also created a stream consumer from which the lambda consumes data. When I try to deploy this to my account, I get the below error:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: Cannot access event source. Please ensure the role can perform the DescribeStreamSummary, ListShards, GetShardIterator and GetRecords actions on your stream and SubscribeToShard on your consumer in IAM.
```

Below is the lambda IAM role created:

```
    lambdaRole.attachInlinePolicy(
      new moteiam.SecurePolicy(this, 'Policy1', {
        policyName: "Policy1",
        statements: [
          new moteiam.SecurePolicyStatement({
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: [
              'kinesis:DescribeStreamSummary',
              'kinesis:GetShardIterator',
              'kinesis:ListShards',
              'kinesis:SubscribeToShard',
              'kinesis:DescribeStream',
              'kinesis:ListStreams',
              'kinesis:DescribeStreamConsumer',
              'kinesis:GetRecords',
            ],
            resources: [streamArn],
          }),
          new moteiam.SecurePolicyStatement({
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: [
              'kms:*',
            ],
            resources: ['*'],
          }),
          new moteiam.SecurePolicyStatement({
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: [
              'kinesis:SubscribeToShard',
            ],
            resources: [KDSConsumer.attrConsumerArn],
          }),
          new moteiam.SecurePolicyStatement({
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: [
              'dynamodb:*',
            ],
            resources: ['*'],
          }),
        ],
      }),
    );

    lambdaRole.addManagedPolicy(
      moteiam.SecureManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'),
    );
    lambdaRole.addManagedPolicy(
      moteiam.SecureManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole'),
    );
```

I also tried adding the `AWSLambdaKinesisExecutionRole` as well (in case I was missing something), but I still get the same error.

Is there anything else that I'm missing?